# Create a rule with Service.Transfer() Behaviour IIS Rewriting Module

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, server.transfer

Is it possible to create a rule that has a behaviour similar to the Service.Transfer from ASP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IIS7 Rewriting Module you can use a `Rewrite Action`.

This keeps the original URL but rewrites the path which your application will see and process in a similar way to `Server.Transfer`.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Have a look at the [rules overview](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/#Rewrite_Rules_Overview).

This essentially is the same as `Context.RewritePath`.

Comment: The thing is avoid using Server.Transfer and use the rewrite module. For the nature of the way the url is called, I can't use Server.Transfer! 

Anyway, thanks for the advice! :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed the IIS URL Rewriting Module in the title, I'll revise.